# How was this cipher created, and how can I solve similar ones?

Tags: cipher

My friend sent me this cipher:

> etsitsiduamuqmuessenon,tsesumissep"omaet"orpdouqmuiterpteangamecovtivamalcxete

She also said it roughly decodes to:

> And I screamed for whatever its worth, 'I love you!' Ain't that the worst thing you've ever heard?

How is this cipher created? How would I be able to solve other ciphers like it?

Comment: Hey welcome to puzzling SE :) You may want to tag this reverse-puzzling or puzzle-identification depending on whether you know the answer yourself (the latter if you don't).

Comment: Have you asked your friend for any hints?

Comment: If you return to this site, please mark HTM's answer as accepted if it is satisfactory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you

> reverse the ciphered text, you get:
>
>  **etexclamavitvocemagnaetpretiumquodpro"teamo"pessimusest,nonesseumqumaudististe**
>
>  which, when spaces are added, becomes (in my best estimation):
>
>  **Et exclamavit voce magna et pretium quod pro "te amo" pessimus est, non esse umqum audistis te**

This is apparently

> a rough translation of the given decoded text into Latin, which you can verify for yourself on [Google](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=Et%20exclamavit%20voce%20magna%20et%20pretium%20quod%20pro%20%22te%20amo%22%20pessimus%20est%2C%20non%20esse%20umqum%20audistis%20te&op=translate) [Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=en&tl=la&text=And%20I%20screamed%20for%20whatever%20its%20worth%2C%20%27I%20love%20you!%27%20Ain%27t%20that%20the%20worst%20thing%20you%27ve%20ever%20heard%3F&op=translate), for instance.

Why this specific text I'm not entirely sure of, but

> it appears to be a lyric in the Taylor Swift song ["Cruel Summer"](https://genius.com/Taylor-swift-cruel-summer-lyrics), so perhaps you are/your friend is a [Swiftie](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Swiftie), and this "cipher" is testing your knowledge on her songs?

Comment: In particular, rot13(guvf vf abg n pvcure ng nyy, ohg fbzr bgure xvaq bs rapbqvat).